# jQuery UI Autocomplete with custom JSON object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jQuery UI Autocomplete (code below) works just fine when the returned JSON is an Array. But my returned JSON is an object that contains an array. So instead of being `Rows[]` it's `Object.Rows[]`

I can't seem to get the syntax right below. I would have thought item would have just switched to item.Rows, but that did not seem to work. Help

```
$('#reportingLocationLookup').autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    delay: 1000, //milliseconds,  
    source: function (request, response) {
        var dto = { 'term': request.term, 'take': 10 };
        //Ajax
        var urlMethod = window.siteRoot + "Invoices/ListPostalLocations";
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(dto);
        window.SendAjax(urlMethod, jsonData, response);
    },
    focus: function () {
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a>" + item.PostalCode + " - " + item.CityAlias + ", " + item.StateAbbreviation + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: I think you didnt format your code right, something is missing.

Comment: All the code is there. I use this code in other spots and it works just fine when item is an array at the root. But when the array is off the root it doesn't like it.

Comment: I didn't show the SendAjax method, but it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autocomplete widget expects an `Array` to be supplied to the `response` function. What this means is that you're going to have to tweak the `success` argument of your `SendAjax` call:

```
/* snip */
source: function (request, response) {
    var dto = { 'term': request.term, 'take': 10 };
    //Ajax
    var urlMethod = window.siteRoot + "Invoices/ListPostalLocations";
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(dto);
    window.SendAjax(urlMethod, jsonData, function(data) {
        response(data.Rows);
    });
},
/* snip */
```

Basically, send `response` (autocomplete's supplied callback function) the array in your response object.